# Query work in PhpMyAdmin but does not work in php code

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
if ($row_tow['wydane'] == 0){
    $task="UPDATE zamowienia 
            SET status_zam=0, data_aktualizacji=NOW() 
            WHERE id_firmy='".$_SESSION["id_firmy"]."' AND nrzamowienia='".$row_tow['nrzamowienia']."'";
    $mysqli->query($task);
}
```

That query changes only `status_zam`, but `data_aktualizacji` isn't updated.
Query works fine at phpmyadmin.

```
            $results_tow = $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(ilosc_zlecona_kuchni) as ilosc_zlecona_kuchni, CURTIME() AS datateraz, nazwa_towaru, uwagi, dodatek, wydane, odebrane, TIME_FORMAT(godz, '%H:%i') AS godz, data_zam  FROM `produkty` WHERE nrzamowienia='".$row['nrzamowienia']."' AND id_firmy='".$_SESSION["id_firmy"]."' AND DATA_ZAM = CURDATE() GROUP BY nrtowaru, dodatek, nazwa_towaru, uwagi, wydane, odebrane, godz");



        if ($results_tow) 
        {
            echo "\t<table class=\"table\">\n";
            echo "\t\t<tr><th>Nazwa</th><th>Godz</th><th>Ilość</th></tr>\n";
                while($row_tow = $results_tow->fetch_assoc())
                {



                    //print_r($row_tow);
                    /*
                     [id] => 4
                    [id_firmy] => 
                    [lic] => BRAK
                    [data] => 15.10.09
                    [godz] => 11:10:15
                    [jedn_miary] => POR.
                    [status_zam] => 0
                    [nrdania] => 0
                    [data_realizacji] => 
                    [godz_realizacji] => 
                    [nrsali] => 0
                    [nrstolika] => 0
                    [nroperatora] => 1
                    [uwagi] => 
                    [czas_przygotowania] => 0
                    [masa_wprowadzona_przez_kucharza] => 0
                    [nrmag] => 3
                    [Identyfikar] => 290
                    [flagi_towaru] => 3
                    [drukarki_kuchenne] => 3
                    [Ident_dok] => 22
                    [nrtowaru] => 5
                    [dodatek] => 0
                    [minutnik] => 0
                    [status_w_zamowieniu] => 9
                    [status_zamowienia] => 5
                    [wydane] => 0
                    */



                    //zmiana statusu zamowienia na nowe, jesli zostanie dodany nowy produkt
                    if($row_tow['wydane']==0){
                        $task="UPDATE zamowienia SET status_zam=0, data_aktualizacji=NOW() WHERE id_firmy='".$_SESSION["id_firmy"]."' AND nrzamowienia='".$row_tow['nrzamowienia']."'";
                        $mysqli->query($task);
                    }
                    $dataakt = $row_tow['data']." ".$row_tow['godz'];
                    $czasakt = strtotime($dataakt);
                    $datateraz = $row_tow['datateraz'];
                    $czasteraz = strtotime($datateraz);

                    //echo $czasakt." teraz: ";
                    //echo $czasteraz;
                    //echo "wynik: ".($czasteraz - $czasakt);

                        echo ( (($czasteraz - $czasakt) >= 1200)&&($row_tow['wydane'] == 0)  ? "\t\t<tr class=\"blink\">\n" : "\t\t<tr>\n" );
                        //echo "\t\t\t<td>".$row_tow['symbol_towaru']."</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t\t<td>".
                        ($row_tow['dodatek'] == 0 ? ($row_tow['wydane'] == 1 ? ($row_tow['odebrane'] == 1 ? "<b><del style='color: orange'>".$row_tow['nazwa_towaru']."</del></b>" : "<b><span style='color: green'>".$row_tow['nazwa_towaru']."</span></b>" ) : "<b style='color: black;'>".$row_tow['nazwa_towaru']."</b>") : ($row_tow['wydane'] == 1 ? ($row_tow['odebrane'] == 1 ? "<del style='color: orange'>".$row_tow['nazwa_towaru']."</del>" : "<span style='color:green'>".$row_tow['nazwa_towaru']."</span>" ) : $row_tow['nazwa_towaru'])); 
                        if(strlen($row_tow['uwagi'])>0) echo "<br /><i>".$row_tow['uwagi']."</i>";

                        echo "</td>\n";
                        echo "<td>".$row_tow['godz']."</td>";
                        echo "\t\t\t<td>".number_format($row_tow['ilosc_zlecona_kuchni']*0.001, 2 , ",", " ")."</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t</tr>\n";
                        //echo "<li>". ."</li>\n";
                }
            echo "\t</table>\n";
        }
        else echo "Brak pozycji towarowych".$mysqli->error;
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would only update one column. Either it works and updates both, or fails and it doesn't update anything.

Comment: What is the data type of data_aktualizacji? If it's a Timestamp column, you could use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of now()

Comment: Is `$row_tow` coming from another query? You should join the queries into a single `UPDATE` instead of doing updates in a loop.

Comment: Do you have session_start(); at the top of  your script?

Comment: @lazy_coder that doesn't matter.

Comment: `echo $task;` and look at what it's trying to run.

Comment: `$row_tow['nrzamowienia']` doesn't exist..?

Comment: Thank you mkaatman!! Problem were at $results_tow.